# Error: Requiring namespace 'Gdk' version '4.0', but '3.0' is already loaded

Tags: ruby, gtk3

I have a Linux install on a laptop. Ubuntu Mate 17.10.1. I installed Ruby 2.5.0 in a sub-directory in my home directory. When attempting to run a Ruby program that requires gtk3, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /home/david/Public/zeta-code-example-1-laptop.rb:17:in `<main>'
    5: from /home/david/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/gtk3-3.2.1/lib/gtk3.rb:40:in `const_missing'
    4: from /home/david/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/gtk3-3.2.1/lib/gtk3.rb:64:in `init'
    3: from /home/david/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/gdk3-3.2.1/lib/gdk3.rb:59:in `init'
    2: from /home/david/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/gdk3-3.2.1/lib/gdk3/x11-loader.rb:21:in `load'
    1: from /home/david/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.2.1/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:37:in `load'
/home/david/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.2.1/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:37:in `require': Requiring namespace 'Gdk' version '4.0', but '3.0' is already loaded (GObjectIntrospection::RepositoryError::NamespaceVersionConflict)
```

I have run the program on my desktop with a similar setup with no problem. I have the appropriate gems installed under /home/david/.gem.
I have a number of other programs requiring gtk3. I get the same errors with them, also.

Also, using the distro's Ruby (2.3) with the appropriate gems installed, I get the same results.

I have done a fair amount of searching online about this and have not found anything relevant.

Anyone know what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your program use bundler?  Is there a `Gemfile` in the application? How does the application load the gems?

Comment: No. I compiled ruby 2.5.0 from source and installed it in my home directory. I prefer to do it this way and I have done so in the past. In fact, I have the same setup on my desktop computer and do not have any problems with it. I have a number of gems installed and they appear to work fine. David

Comment: The error shows a version conflict but it's hard to debug because you've not posted any code and we don't know how your gem is getting loaded into your program.

Comment: I load the gem or gems into my program by using "require" like this: require 'gtk3'

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates a version conflict.  Try the following steps:

Go to the root of your application and run:

```
gem list gtk
```

See if you have the correct version you expect and if any other versions may also be installed.  Then try:

```
gem uninstall gtk3
gem install gtk3
```

If you still get the error, check to see if other gems your app is loading may require a different version.  As a test try:

```
gem install pry
```

Launch a Pry session:

```
pry
```

From the Pry shell type:

```
require 'gtk3'
cd Gtk
show-method Loader
```

you should see a method like this:

```
def load
  self.version = "3.0"
   super("Gtk")
end
```

and

```
!!!
```

will get you out of the Pry shell.

From here you know you're able to load the correct version of Gtk so again, it must be something else trying to load the wrong/another version.

Also make sure you update your system dependencies using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: In test program:

#start excerpted code fragment
require 'gtk3'
require 'pry'

binding.pry
class RubyApp < Gtk::Window

def initialize
#end excerpted code fragment

Running the program:
    19: def load
    20:   self.version = "3.0"
 => 21:   super("Gdk")
    22: end

Then, finishing:
/home/david/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.2.1/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:37:in `require': Requiring namespace 'Gdk' version '4.0', but '3.0' is already loaded (GObjectIntrospection::RepositoryError::NamespaceVersionConflict)

Comment: Sorry about that formatting, I'm not experienced with posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem. It turned out that I had apparently installed
gir1.2-gtk-4.0 from synaptic along with some other software when
I first set up my system. I do not think it was installed by default.

I uninstalled that file and my graphical programs ran fine.
This file was not on my desktop computer and I had no problems with it.

The responses to my post were intelligent and appreciated.